# What does aiMesh::mMethod in assimp mean?

Tags: assimp

In `aiMesh` there is a field `mMethod`:

```
struct aiMesh {
    /*...*/

    /**
     *  Method of morphing when anim-meshes are specified.
     */
    unsigned int mMethod;

    /*...*/
};
```

How many different methods of morphing are there and what are there corresponding integer values?

Answer (score 0):

From digging through the source of the Collada loader this is `aiMorphingMethod`:

```
/** @brief Enumerates the methods of mesh morphing supported by Assimp.
 */
enum aiMorphingMethod {
    /** Interpolation between morph targets */
    aiMorphingMethod_VERTEX_BLEND = 0x1,

    /** Normalized morphing between morph targets  */
    aiMorphingMethod_MORPH_NORMALIZED = 0x2,

    /** Relative morphing between morph targets  */
    aiMorphingMethod_MORPH_RELATIVE = 0x3,

}; //! enum aiMorphingMethod
```

The code comment on `mMethod` should probably be updated to mention `aiMorphingMethod`.

Comment: This has been fixed.  See here:  https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/4320 and here https://github.com/assimp/assimp/pull/4321